# Forward Time Centered Space Scheme on unit square, Stability Analysis

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

I'm stumped on the following problem:

Show that 
$u(x,y,t)=\exp(1.68t)\sin(1.2(x-y))\cosh(x+2y)$  solves 
$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}-2\frac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial x^2}-\frac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial y^2}=0$
using a forward time centered space scheme on the unit square. Then write down details of the numerical scheme and derive the stability condition of $\Delta t$ on $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$.

---

I know what the FTCS scheme is (see below), but am not quite sure how to apply it to the above equations to show that $u(x,y,t)$ does, infact, solve the problem. Also, how would you suggest going about the stability analysis?

FTCS scheme (please correct me if I'm wrong):
$f_i^{n+1}=f_i^n+\left( \frac{\Delta t}{\Delta x ^2}\right)(f^n_{i+1}-2f_i^n+f^n_{i-1})$

Thanks!